# Do foreign keys add something to PHP SQL requests?

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys

I have a database, with some tables and foreign keys.

```
persons
+----------+----------+----------+
|id_person |     name |      age |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        |    Smith | 45       |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        |    Maure | 76       |
+----------+----------+----------+

cars
+----------+----------+----------+
|   id_car |    color | id_owner*|
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        |      red | 1        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        |     gray | 2        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 3        |    white | 2        |
+----------+----------+----------+
*id_owner has a FOREIGN KEY constraint to persons.id_person
```

I know how this impacts `INSERT` queries, by limiting the possible values of the foreign key to those of the pointed key.

```sql
INSERT INTO cars (id_car, color, id_owner) VALUES (NULL, "darkGray", 2) -- will add a car to the cars table.
INSERT INTO cars (id_car, color, id_owner) VALUES (NULL, "rainbow", 3) -- won't work because "3" is not a valid id_person
```

But does this change anything in a `select` query ?

```sql
SELECT c.color, p.name
FROM cars c
    LEFT JOIN persons p ON p.id_person = c.id_owner -- returns [["red", "Smith"], ["gray", "Maure"], ["white", "Maure"]]
```

Comment: In what way should it change the select? Are you facing issues? Please clarify

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you surprised at what a left join does or what is the problem?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it makes the query faster or something like that...

Comment: Foreign key columns are required to have an index on them. When you don't create one, MySQL creates one for you. Compared to having no index it is faster, yes (unless you have so few rows in the table, that it's cheaper to not do the extra lookup in the index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the presence of a foreign key relationship between two tables will not cause any change/addition in the data returned by a select that uses those tables, compared to a setup that has identical tables but no fk relationship

Try it for yourself: run the select in one tab, remove the foreign key and rerun the same select in another tab. The output will be identical